# python unmanaged dll call, fails on win32 FindWindow api with Access Violation

Tags: python, dll, unmanaged, access-violation

I have the following bare minimum function in a DLL

```
#define INTELHOOK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)    
INTELHOOK_API BOOL testFunc(void) {
    BOOL success = false;
    HWND parent = NULL;

    parent = FindWindow("Arium.SourcePont", NULL);
    if (parent != NULL) {
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}
```

If I call this from the main function in the DLL it works fine. If I call it from python I get the following:

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00439508
```

My python script looks like this:

```
from ctypes import *
dll = cdll.hook
print dll.testFunc()
```

I'm running on win7, 64-bit but both the dll and python are 32-bit:

```
c:\Projects\hg\hooklib>dumpbin /headers hook.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file hook.dll
PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
```

'

> > > print sys.version
> > >           2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

I attached a debugger but can't seem to solve it.

```
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Python27\python.exe'
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll'
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PGPmapih.dll'
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Python27\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd'
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'python.exe': Loaded 'C:\Projects\hg\hooklib\hook.dll', Symbols loaded.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x10b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x01d428ae (hook.dll) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00439508.
The program '[3836] python.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

The same happens when I access the function with Java through JNA.
Given that the function works while calling from the main in the dll makes me believe it's some access restriction, but that doesn't make sense. I can't be the first one calling win32 functions indirectly in dll's...

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read all this!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this works fine for me in 32-bit Windows XP with Python 3.2.1 and 2.7.2, compiled with i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe version 4.5.3:

c/test.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define INTELHOOK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
INTELHOOK_API BOOL test(void) {
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    HWND parent = NULL;

    parent = FindWindow("notepad", NULL);
    if (parent != NULL) {
        success = TRUE;
    }
    return success;
}

// g++ test.cpp -o test.dll -shared
```

test.py:

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('c/test.dll')
print(dll.test())
```

It prints 1 if a Notepad window is open, else 0.

Answer (score 1):

@eryksun
Thank you for trying. Your answer lead me to find the solution.

I was missing the MSVC equivalent to GCC's -shared (which is /LD) while compiling.

I initially developed and tested the DLL functions from C, then added exports but forgot to add the /LD option.

I'll mark this question as solved, but I still wonder why it causes an access violation if I don't have a proper DllMain.